# definition of $\pi$ in terms of $\cos$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, pi

I have to define $\pi$ in terms of cos and to show why the definition is well-defined.

I think that I haven't understood what it is asking because $\pi$ would be the angle that divided for $2$ gives me $0$ to me.

But it is clearly far from the purpose of the exercise.

Can someone help me to understand?

Comment: Hint: Think about the zeros of the cosine function.

Comment: What *definition* of $\cos$ is used?

Comment: Yes, we generally define $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as the first positive zero of $\cos$ defined as a power series. The division by $2$ is indeed artificial...

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider $\displaystyle \cos(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ and $\displaystyle \sin(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

We can show both have infinite radius of convergence and that they are each other derivatives (with proper signs).

This allows to get also $(\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2)'=-2\cos(x)\sin(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)=0$ so the sum is constant and equal to $\cos(0)^2+\sin(0)^2=1$

Since $\cos(0)=1>0$ let's make the hypothesis that $\cos$ has no zero, i.e. $\forall x,\ \cos(x)>0$.

The derivatives relation implies that $\sin(x)\nearrow$ on $[0,+\infty)$

Since $\sin$ is increasing then:

- $\sin(1)>\sin(0)=0$
- $\displaystyle \cos(1)-\cos(x)=\int_1^x \sin(t)\mathop{dt}\ge \int_1^x \sin(1)\mathop{dt}\ge (x-1)\sin(1)\to +\infty$

We get $\cos(x)\to -\infty$ which is a contradiction with the hypothesis that $\cos(x)$ is always positive.

Thus $\cos$ annulates on $[0,+\infty)$ and we define $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ as its first positive zero.

(it exists and is uniquely defined as minimum of a non empty, closed and bounded inferiorly real set $E=\{x\ge 0\mid \cos(x)=0\}$)

*Then I let you go on verifying that $\sin(\frac\pi 2)=1$, and that $2\pi$ is the smallest period of $\sin,\cos$, both results obtainable from the derivatives, and the trigonometric addition formulas.*

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable definition:
$$\pi = 2\sup\{x > 0\,\vert\,\forall t\in[0,x]:\,\cos(t) > 0\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can define $\pi$ as the smallest real number greater than or equal to $0$ such its cosine is equal to $-1$.

Comment: it is well-defined because  it is the smallest of all, isn't it?

Comment: I thought the question was to explain the exercise, not to solve it :).

Comment: Yes, but you will have also to prove that ther is some $x\geqslant0$ such that $\cos x=-1$. And that there *has* to be a smallest such number.

Comment: @Alexey As you can see from me previous comment, there is yet a lot to do.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I could say that $\pi= min \left \{ x \in R, x \ge 0, cos x=-1\right \} $   and the minimum is unambiguous,

Comment: @Anne Yes, but the minimum of a set of reals isn't always well-defined. There are two or three things that can cause problems in general. You have to show that those do not apply here.

Answer (score 1):

> I think that I haven't understood what it is asking because $\pi$ would be the angle that divided for 2 gives me 0 to me.
>
> But it is clearly far from the purpose of the exercise.

What you suggest here is indeed (except that your phrasing is a bit sloppy) a common definition of $\pi$ and I don't think you need to assume it is not exactly the definition the exercise asks for.

As has already been pointed out, there's plenty of things you still need to do to prove that this definition *actually defines* something.

You could also do what José Carlos Santos suggests and look for solutions to $\cos(x)=-1$ instead of $\cos(x)=0$.

But immediately it seems to be easier to prove that $\cos(x)=0$ must have a solution in the correct range -- for example, you can evaluate $\cos(1)$ and $\cos(2)$ using the power series to sufficient precision that you can appeal to the Intermediate Value Theorem to show there must be a zero between them.

Comment: sorry, but I'm trying to understand what to do... if I evaluate cos(1) and cos(2) where should I consider the center of the series? and then, should I write cos(1)-cos(2)  and to prove that this series tends to 0?

Comment: @Anne: If you evaluate a few terms of the series you'll pretty soon have enough information to know that $\cos(1)>0$ and $\cos(2)<0$. The intermediate value theorem then tells you that there is an $x\in[1,2]$ where $\cos(x)=0$.

Comment: ok, I think it is clear to me what you said, but I have a doubt relating to the necessity of prove that there a zero for cos $\pi$...it seems so obvious that there should be a zero in $\pi/2$ that I don't see why should I demonstrate this

Comment: @Anne: You must be misunderstanding something; nobody has said you should prove $\cos(\pi)=0$ (which would be silly because it's not true). On the other hand, if you want to define $\pi$ as $2x$ where $x$ is the (appropriate) solution to $\cos(x)=0$, then you need to prove that $\cos(x)=0$ _has_ a solution at all -- otherwise the definition would not work.

Comment: independently by what value of cosx I'm trying to demonstrate, it seems very obvious that is that exact value. I was observing that because you are trying to demonstrate that cos x=0

Answer (score 1):

I think the best definition is
\begin{equation}
\pi = 2\int_0^1 \frac{d x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}
\end{equation}
or perhaps
\begin{equation}
\pi = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d x}{1 + x^2}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$\pi$ can be written in terms of $\cos$ as follows:

$$\pi = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{n+1/2}\sqrt {1-\cos\left(\left(\frac{180}{2^n}\right)^\circ\right)}$$

Comment: The expression on the right hand side uses $\pi$, so it can't be used to define $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks,  I updated it.