# Proof of sign of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I would like to know if there is a way to proof that $\cos(x)\geq0$ if $x \in [\frac{-\pi}{2};\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $\cos(x) \leq 0$ if $x \in [\frac{\pi}{2};\frac{3\pi}{2}]$ knowing only that $f :(\mathbb R, +) \to (\mathbb C(1), \times)$ that from an angle $\theta$ gives the complex number $e^{i\theta}$ is a morphism so $\operatorname{ker} f = 2\pi \mathbb Z$, also knowing $\cos(\theta) = \Re(e^{i\theta})$, $\sin(\theta) = \Im(e^{i\theta})$, knowing $e^{i\pi}=-1$ all summation and duplication rules of $\cos$ and $\sin$. We are also allowed to use derivative formulas.

I really don't see any way to do it. My final goal is to show that $\cos(2\pi/3)$ is negative only with this tools...

Comment: Are you allowed to use the uniqueness of solutions to the initial value problem in differential equations? In particular, do you know that $y''+y=0$ has two unique independent solutions that satisfy $y_1(0) = 1, y_1'(0) = 0$ and $ y_2(0) = 0, y_2'(0) = 1$ resp.?

Comment: I have shown https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3177297/399263 relation between $\pi$ and $\cos$ using series, but used only $c^2+s^2=1$ and $c'=-s,s'=c$. Are you allowed to get this from your premises ?

Comment: Yes we know that $(e^{ix})′ = ie^{ix}, cos(x)′ = − sin(x), sin(x)′ = cos(x).

Comment: We aren't allowed to use series, only algebra, no analysis, seems to be "impossible"